# Assigning values received from api calls for each element in the loop iteration using Observables

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

I have a foreach loop through which I am iterating and want to call functions which would in turn make async api calls and return value which can be rendered in the html.

The 1st function call **getCurrentValue()** would return currentTemperatureRef which I finally want to assign **receivedCurrentValue** and render in html

The 2nd function call **getDesiredValue1()** would return **desiredValueToBeReturned** which I finally want to assign **receivedDesiredValue1** and render in html

ts

```
myObj = { droppedItem: [] };
elements = [
   { elementId: 1, elementName: "name1" },
   { elementId: 2, elementName: "name2" },
   { elementId: 3, elementName: "name3" },
   { elementId: 4, elementName: "name4" }
 ];

this.elements.forEach(element => {

    let receivedCurrentValue = this.getCurrentValue(element.name);
    let receivedDesiredValue1 = this.getDesiredValue1(element.id);


 this.myObj.droppedItem.push(receivedCurrentValue)
 this.myObj.droppedItem.push(receivedDesiredValue1)

}

getCurrentValue(eleName){

 //1st api(async api call)
 var ref = this.helperService.getPointIdbyTags(this.existingObj, ['current', 
          'temp'], eleName)[0];

 //2nd api(async api call which expects ref value from above api call)
 this.siteService.getHisPointData(ref, 'current')
                    .pipe(
                        map(this.helperService.stripHaystackTypeMapping),
                    )
                    .subscribe(({ rows }) => {
                        if (rows.length > 0) {
                            this.currentTemperatureRef = rows[0].val;
                        }
                    });
}

getDesiredValue1(eleId){
 //1st async api call
 this.siteService.getScheduleParamsByRoomRef('temp and air and desired and 
 heating', eleId)
   .subscribe(function (a) {
    let row = a;

      let pointId = this.helperService.stripHaystackTypeMapping(row['id']).split(' ')[0];

      //2nd async api call expecting pointId from above api call
       this.siteService.getHisPointData(pointId, 'current')
         .subscribe(function (a) {
                    let rows = a.rows,
                    if (rows.length > 0) {
                    let desiredValueToBeReturned = rows[0].val;
            )
           }
  )
 }
}
```

html

```
<div *ngFor="let existingItem of myObj?.droppedItem">
<span>{{existingItem.receivedValue}}</span>
<span>{{existingItem.receivedDesiredValue1}}</span>
<span>{{existingItem.receivedDesiredValue2}}</span>
</div>
```

**Update**

when I try to

```
getCurrentValue(eleName){
    let roomObj = this.getRoomObj(eleName);
    let equipRef = roomObj.map(equip => equip.entities.filter(entity => entity.entities.length > 0)[0])[0];

    return this.helperService.getPointIdbyTags(this.buildings, ['current', 
             'temp'], equipRef.referenceIDs.room)[0].pipe(switchMap((res:any)=>{
                   //we don't want "res" else the response of 
                   return  this.siteService.getHisPointData(res, 'current')
                       .pipe(
                           map(this.helperService.stripHaystackTypeMapping),
                       )
              }));
}
```

I get an error on line => return this.helperService.getPointIdbyTags(this.buildings, ['current', 
             'temp'], equipRef.referenceIDs.room)[0].pipe(switchMap(

> ERROR TypeError: this.helperService.getPointIdbyTags(...)[0].pipe is
>   not a function

Comment: What exactly is the question here? Also, is all the code posted in the question relevant here?

Comment: @NicholasK  I am new to using observable , so needed help , while I iterate through for each loop , how can I can make async api calls and on receving the response display on html for all the elements

Comment: Sorry but your question is still very unclear. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't undestand so much the question, but you need understand some about forkJoin and switchMap. SwitchMap it's usefull when you need make two calls one depending the response of the another. The construction becomes like

```
callOne.pipe(
  switchMap(resposeOfCallOne=>{
      return callTwo(responseOfCallOne)
  })
```

If subscribe you received the response of callTwo

forkJoin get an array of calls and return the result in an array

```
forkJoin([callOne,callTwo])
```

if subscribe you received an array: res[0] has the response of callOne and res[1] the response of callTwo

Well, First convert your functions getCurrentValue and getDesiredValue1 to return observables

```
getCurrentValue(eleName){

 return this.helperService.getPointIdbyTags(this.existingObj, ['current', 
          'temp'], eleName)[0].pipe(switchMap((res:any)=>{
                //we don't want "res" else the response of 
                return  this.siteService.getHisPointData(ref, 'current')
                    .pipe(
                        map(this.helperService.stripHaystackTypeMapping),
                    )
           };
}

getDesiredValue1(eleId){
 return this.siteService.getScheduleParamsByRoomRef('temp and air and desired and 
 heating', eleId).pipe(
      switchMap((a:any)=>{
        let row = a;
        let pointId = this.helperService.stripHaystackTypeMapping(row['id']).split(' ')[0];
        return this.siteService.getHisPointData(pointId, 'current')
      }))
```

Well, when we has an element we want create the two calls, we are going to use forkjoin

We want to make, forEach element create two calls, so we can make

```
this.elements.forEach(element => {
   forkJoin([this.getCurrentValue(element.name),this.getDesiredValue1(element.id)])
    .subscribe(([current,desired])=>{
        element.current=current;
        element.desired=desired;
    })
})
```

I user in subscribe ([current,desired]) but we can use res and use element.current=res[0],element.desired=res[1]

If we want, we can even make only one subscription -now we has so many subscriptions as element we have-

```
arrayOfCalls=[]
this.elements.forEach(element => {
   arrayOfCalls.push(
     forkJoin([this.getCurrentValue(element.name),this.getDesiredValue1(element.id)])
   )
}
//then subscribe
arrayOfCalls.subscribe((fullRes:any[])=>{
    fullRes.map((res,index)=>{
       this.elements[index].currentValue=res[0]
       this.elements[index].desiredValue=res[1]
    })
})
```

Comment: thanks for such a detailed explanation, I was stuggling to create a reproducible example as it has api calls involved , one query I had , I am using a foreach loop and then I call functions making api call and once I receive the values I'll assign to the html variables , my doubt is like if api calls take too long to return the response what will happen to => .subscribe(([current,desired])=>{
        element.current=current;
        element.desired=desired;

Comment: Well, the problem with forkJoin is that not return any value else all the calls are completed. In that case, I suggested you re-thinking the API to allow send an array of elements, and return the response, but it's another question not angular theme

Comment: Your answer is correct , I also wanted to know like is there a way to handle the kind of situation , like in case no respoanse is recevied or response is failed for a particular element, after that also it should keep on iterating the main => this.elements.forEach(element => {  , for rest of the elements further

Comment: I have updated the post , I am getting an erro , could you please suggest what needs to be corrected, thanks

Comment: there're a type error (missing a parenthesis): `this.helperService.getPointIdbyTags(this.buildings, ['current', 
             'temp'], equipRef.referenceIDs.room)[0]**)**.pipe(...)`

Comment: sorry, this.helper.getPointIdByTags(...) is an observable. I supouse that return an array of one element, so the sintax correct is `this.helper.getPointIdByTags(...).pipe(switchMap((resarray:any[])=>{const res=resarray[0];..}))` see that this.helper return an array, I use an auxiliar variable res that get the unique element